# UIPopoverController takes control and won't let go

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, first-responder

I have a few Popovers that I present from UIBarButtonItems.

The popovers are Property settings for an Object, Color, Size, Positioning, name, line thickness, etc.

As the settings in the popover change, the Object they are properties for also changes in realtime.

Most of the time a tap away from the popover clears it. Though sometimes something happens to the environment where the responder chain seems to be broken and a tap away from the popover no longer dismisses the popover.   The Property controls in the popover still work, though there is no way to dismiss the popover.

On Popovers with TextFields, I can alter the text, dismiss the Keyboard and then I can Dismiss the popover normally.

Any Tips on where to start Logging and see who's on top of the responder chain and who's able to receive gestures/touches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I was debugging recognizers and such (similar), I put a UITapGestureRecognizer on the main background view, calling a method viewTapped:. In viewTapped: you can dismiss any outstanding popovers (handy if they are properties of the VC). You can also send resignFirstResponder if you worry about any textFields that might not be cooperating.

Are you setting any passthrough views? You might examine those. Normally you don't have any ability to tap outside the popover without dismissing unless you specifically set the passthroughViews.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: the popover is onto of a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` does have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it, That is how the popover is normally dismissed.  For the `UITextFields`, they are on the Popover. Editing the Text In the Popover and then dismissing the Keyboard, usually lets me then dismiss the popover by tapping the `UIScrollView`.   PassthroughViews? What's that?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you are on the right track - play around with the recognizers and have fun.

Comment: On the Right Track?  (-;  The TapGestureRecognizer has been there from the get go. (-;  I'll add in some NSLogs and see whats active.   Any tips on troubleshooting the responder chain? PassthroughViews?  I do have a DoubleTapGesture and a ScrollToTop on the Scroll View and I can always get the ScrollToTop to fire in the popover lockdown, and on occasion the double tap.